# Update all the values of the json document to default value using pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a JSON document in the following format,

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54a2462820fb5b6068b45b05"),
    "Ref": 1,
    "a": {
        "b": "value1",
        "c": "value2",
        "d": {
            "e": "value3"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to update values of all the keys even nested (Ref,b,c,e) except _id to some default value say 'na' at once. I think it is not possible using mongo Query.

Any way to do this in pymongo programmatically? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: `a,b,c,d,e` is dynamic key or you know in advance key name ?

Comment: They are dynamic. No of fields may vary for each document

Comment: For updating dynamic keys in mongodb using `update` query not possible, you should change your document structure or use programming code to update dynamic values .

Comment: Consider adding explicitly how you want the transformed data to look? Why not delete the keys and then have code default to NA if a key is missing when it's read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function to Update values of all keys except _id to default value. Then use [`save()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db-collection-save) to update your documents.

```
def recurse_keys(document):
    for key in document.keys():
        if isinstance(document[key], dict):
            recurse_keys(document[key])
        else:
            if key != '_id':
                document[key]='NA'


//update your document, save behaves as upsert with '_id' supplied.
db.collection.save(document)
```